# Vue.js - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__services_Api__.a.post is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Everytime I click the register button i get this error:

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__services_Api__.a.post is not a function**

The AuthenticationService.js has the following code:

```js
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  register (credentials) {
    return Api.post('register', credentials)
  }
}
```

Api.js has the following code:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8081/`
  })
}
```

This is the code for app.js:

```js
console.log('Sup?')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')

const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    message: `${req.body.email} Registered!`
  })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081)
```

Register.vue has this code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <input 
      type="email" 
      name="email"
      v-model="email"
      placeholder="email"/>
    <br>
    <input 
      type="password" 
      name="password"
      v-model="password"
      placeholder="password"/>
    <br>
    <button @click="register">
      Register
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async register () {
      await AuthenticationService.register({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      })
      console.log('done!')
    }
  }
  // watch: {
  //   email (value) {
  //     console.log('email changed: ', value)
  //   }
  // }
}
</script>
```

Index.js has this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Register from '@/components/Register'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: Register
    }
  ]
})
```

The hierarchy is as under:[Project Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OFXp.png)

You can get this project at this link:
[VueDev](https://github.com/billdhar/VueDev)

Comment: Your api exports a function that returns an instance when called, however you try to access a the instance methods without creating one.

Comment: I'm trying to learn web development using Vue.js. This is really new to me and I'm trying. Can you explain how I can solve it here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue
I guess problem is here :

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
 register (credentials) {
  return Api.post('register', credentials)
 }
}
```

But there should be:

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  register (credentials) {
   return Api().post('register', credentials)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to export the instance itself, not a function:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:8081/`
})

export default instance
```

Comment: I tried that, now I'm getting these errors:
OPTIONS http://localhost:8081/register net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

And this:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error

Comment: Are you working in an environment with a proxy? That can cause problems sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. No, I'm not working in an environment with a proxy.

Comment: Can you please mark this question as answered for other questioners? The original question is solved I think.